# No indicators showing up on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, indicator

I can't seem to get any indicators on my new installation of Ubuntu, I'm on a laptop so seeing the battery is pretty important, along with it just being a nuisance.

I've tried installing the indicator applet and using dconf, but they're still not showing up.

In case this matters, I had quite a few problems installing this distro, one being the 'low graphics' error, so I had to switch from lightdm then use proprietary drivers after that. Don't know if it's relevant but it might help.

Here's a screenshot of what it looks like.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try to install ubuntu-tweak tool.

Then, reset the Unity with [unity-reset tool](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/10/how-to-reset-compiz-and-unity-in-ubuntu.html):

```
$ unity-reset
$ setsid unity
```

If that didn't work out try to re-install unity & desktop:

```
$ sudo apt-get autoremove ubuntu-desktop 
$ sudo apt-get autoremove unity 
$ sudo apt-get update 
$ sudo apt-get install unity
$ sudo apt-get install unity-2d 
$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop 
$ sudo shutdown -r now
```

After that upgrade if you want:

```
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Reinstalling unity fixed it for me. Couple of corrections though:
`unity-reset` does not work. I believe it's `unity reset`.
`sudo shutdown -r` should be `sudo shutdown -r now`.

Answer (score -1):

I'll just document here how I fixed this on 15.10:

After having tried everything with no luck I finally noticed, that the resolution of my external display had changed to 2560x1440 (was 1920x1080 before) and for some reason this resolution made the indicator area not visible. When I changed back to 1920x1080 it was normal again.